# Intuitively, we expect a level set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be a $2$-dimensional surface. Why?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, surfaces

I am watching [a lecture about multivariable mathematics (Math 3500 Day 20: Continuity and Preimages)](https://youtu.be/sGiqDoU4QcU?t=412) by Prof. Theodore Shifrin.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function.
Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number.
Suppose that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x)=c\}\neq\emptyset$.

Intuitively, we expect the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x)=c\}$ to be a $2$-dimensional surface.

(1) Why do we expect this set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x)=c\}$ is $2$-dimensional?

For example, if $f(x) = c$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x)=c\}$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is not a $2$-dimensional surface.
But we don't think this is a typical case.

(2) For what $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, is the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | f(x)=c\}$ $2$-dimensional?

(3) I don't know the definition that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $2$-dimensional. What book should I read?

Comment: Hello :) It is something about $2$-dimensional (differentiable or more generally topological) manifolds, which are sets, that look locally like $\mathbb R^2$.
You are right, if there are no other assumptions on $f$, it could be anything. But it makes sense to suppose $f$ to be bijective and continuous (or even furthermore differentiable).

Comment: @Jochen Thank you very much for your comment. I will try to read a manifold book.

Comment: In your first example, the gradient is $0$. Only if the gradient is nonzero do we expect the level set to be a surface.

Comment: @littleO Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Mikal, Thank you very much for your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be understood as follows. Consider the Jacobian matrix of the function $f$ at a point $p$ with $f(p) = c$. This is a linear approximation for $f$ near $p$, and takes the form of a $1 \times 3$ matrix transformation. Every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the null space of this matrix corresponds to a direction one can move away from $p$ on which $f$ is constant, thus a direction that lies on the set $\{f(x) = c\}$. If the linear transformation is surjective, the null space of the Jacobian is two-dimensional, meaning that the set $\{f(x) = c\}$ is two-dimensional near $p$. This provides the intuitive condition we need for the result to be true: the Jacobian should always be surjective, which when mapping to $\mathbb{R}^1$ just means that it is nonzero.

Comment: Elchanan Solomon, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ and $2)$ if you have $f(x,y,z)=c$ you can plug in any pair $(x,y)$ and then find z, (or several z) so you can visualize z as the height over the point $(x,y)$ of the x,y plane.
Easy examples $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz=d$ is a plain, $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ is a sphere
For more examples get a 3d program like Geogebra 3d and let it plot some f(x,y,z) of your choice.
$3)$ is not true in general, $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4$ is a subset of $R^3$ and not 2d

Comment: trula, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: VIVID, Thank you very much for your edit.